# How would I find all of the community wiki ruby questions?

Tags: support

The title says it all:

How would I find all of the community wiki ruby questions? Or am I not understanding how I would get to them?  Would this be it: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3Ayes+ruby ?

Comment: Why would you need to find exactly those that have been marked CW? Curious, that's all.

Comment: honestly, just curious about the nature of what constitutes a community wiki. the above link searches through text and not the tag so many false positives

Comment: A txtspk and all-lowercase question on Meta = brave! `;-)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Search using the following:

```
[ruby] wiki:yes is:question
```

Breakdown:

```
[ruby]      - the ruby tag
wiki:yes    - is a community wiki 
is:question - is a question
```

Comment: Great, thx. Really appreciate.